# Projecting line onto edge of ellipse?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I feel like the answer to this should be fairly simple, but I am absolutely hitting a brick wall here.

I have a line, with angle $\beta$ and origin $(x_l, y_l)$.

I have a rotated ellipse, with major axes $a$ and $b$, and rotation angle of $\alpha$, around center $(h, k)$.

The parametric equations for the ellipse are:

$x = a \cos t \cos \alpha - b \sin t \sin \alpha + h$

$y = b \sin t \cos \alpha + a \cos t \sin \alpha + k$

Here is a picture describing the scenario/what I want:

[image: Line and ellipse]

The line is in red, and when it would otherwise be on the inside of the ellipse, I want to find the locations that points on the line would have on the border instead. **My line is also discretized into individual points, so essentially I want to find what projection the dotted points would have onto the edge of the ellipse.** Basically, I actually care about how an arbitrary point $(x_p, y_p)$ on the dotted line would be 'pushed outside' the ellipse, and its new coordinates.

I feel like this should really be straight forward, but I'm just very confused about how to proceed - finding the parameter $t$ of the intersecting points seems like the way to start, but how to solve for $t$ in closed form in this case?

Thank you so much for any hints or guidance. Hopefully this is a clear enough explanation!

**EDIT:** Some clarifications. In the following figure, I want to find $(x_e, y_e)$ given $(x_p, y_p)$ given that the blue dotted line is orthogonal to the red dotted line.

[image: Ellipse and line, clarified.]

Comment: How are the points "projected" onto the ellipse? Radially from the center?

Comment: Saying "projection" is making things ambiguous. Projected from the center of the ellipse, or along the major axis? You could also just find the points of intersection and consider the graph as a piecewise union of three pieces.

Comment: ...or from a focus, for that matter, which could be interesting in its own right.

Comment: @travis yes it would :)

Comment: @rschwieb In fact that might be an easier case to solve, since the angular parametrization of the ellipse from a focus is especially nice. Anyway, that would only make sense if both intersections of the ellipse with the line to be projected are on the same side of the line containing the minor axis.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think projection is the wrong word here - not sure what the correct word to use is? I suppose intersection of line and ellipse, but that's not quite right either.
The physical model of this is the ellipse is an obstacle, and we can not pass through the obstacle - but are trying to find the shortest path around (i.e., on the edge of the obstacle).

Ideally, the new points should lie on a line orthogonal to the original red, dotted line, intersecting at $(x_p, y_p)$ though at some point whatever is computationally easier.

Comment: Do you care that there’s a potential discontinuity where the line intersects the ellipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a generic point on the blue line, i.e.

$$P(\lambda) = (x_p,y_p)+\lambda(-\sin\beta,\cos\beta)$$

and plug that into the equation for the ellipse, which will give you a quadratic equation in $\lambda$ whose solutions correspond to the points of intersection. From these two points of intersection, you may want to either pick the one closer to $(x_p,y_p)$ (i.e. the one with smaller absolute value $\lvert\lambda\rvert$) or the one on the chosen side of the red line, (e.g. the one with $\lambda>0$).

For the equation of the ellipse, you need an implicit form. So you subtract the center, undo the rotation and then write down the general form of an axis-aligned and origin-centered ellipse.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha \\
-\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}x-h\\y-k\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
(x-h)\cos\alpha+(y-k)\sin\alpha\\
-(x-h)\sin\alpha+(y-k)\cos\alpha
 \end{pmatrix}
\\
\left(\frac{(x-h)\cos\alpha+(y-k)\sin\alpha}{a}\right)^2+
\left(\frac{-(x-h)\sin\alpha+(y-k)\cos\alpha}{b}\right)^2=1
$$